# Running Bib file

Tags: bibtex

I'm relatively new in Latex and now I want to use bibtex function in my paper.

here is how it"s constructed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage,lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Imperfections in credit market influence the labor market \cite{einstein}.

\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\bibliography{Reference}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

where my bib file is "Reference.bib" and has the following content:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

I'm running Latex, however there is no output of the bibliography in pdf and the citations are with question marks.
Also I have tried to run my bib file separately and it's not creating "bbl" extension file (I'm not sure if it's necessary for creating pdf).

Also when I"m running my bib file separately here is the Console Output I'm getting:

```
 " This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Anushmush/Desktop/Labor Search/Reference.bib")
*"
```

Is this what I need to get?

Could you please help me figure out what is the mistake I'm making here?

Thank you very much

Comment: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: You need to run both LaTeX and BibTeX. Say your main document's name is `report.tex`. Then you can do
`pdflatex report` followed by
`bibtex report` followed by
`pdflatex report`
Then you should get a document with bibliography.

Comment: @ThomasWeise -- actually, if the document contains any `\cite`s, (pdf)latex must be run twice to expand them properly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I am not sure if I understand fully. In my comment, I suggest to first run `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` again, i.e., two times `pdflatex`. Do you mean I should do `pdflatex`, then `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex`? (A special additional case would be references which cite additional references. If that is the case, one may need arbitrarily many `pdflatex`-`bibtex` runs. A solution might be to continue doing that until the size of the `.aux` file does not change anymore. Either way, this seems not to be the case here.)

Comment: @ThomasWeise You need `pdflatex` then `bibtex` then `pdflatex` then `pdflatex` in the standard case. As you say, additional runs may be needed in special cases, but even in the standard case an additional run of `pdflatex` is required if `\cite{}` is used anywhere.

Comment: @cfr, @barbarabeeton: Oh, cool, I didn't know that. (I always repeat my `pdflatex`-> `bibtex` in a loop until the `.aux` or `.pdf`file size does not change anymore.)... Thanks for this lesson ^_^.